# Are the two affine varieties $V(x_2^2-x_1^3-x_1^2)$ and $V(x_1^2-x_2^2-1)$ isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

This is a part of Exercise 4.19 of Gathmann's 2021 notes of Algebraic Geometry.

For $V(x_2^2-x_1^3-x_1^2)$, we have $x_2^2=x_1^2(x_1+1)$ and $ x_2^2-x_1^3-x_1^2$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.

For $V(x_1^2-x_2^2-1)$, we have $x^2_2=(x_1-1)(x_1+1)$ and $x_1^2-x_2^2-1$ is also irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.

Therefore their corresponding rings of regular functions are both not a UFD and are both integral domains.

So it seems not easy to show that these two are not isomorphic by showing that their corresponding rings of regular functions are not isomorphic.

Conversely, I just cannot come up with any reasonable morphism between these two that may be an isomorphism...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The first one has a singular point at the origin but the second one is smooth. Incidentally, the second one is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ (take $u = x_1 - x_2, v = x_1 + x_2$) which shows its ring of regular functions is a UFD. To show that those factorizations are distinct you have to show that they don't differ by multiplication by a unit!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I haven't learnt the smoothness, but really thank you for the "incidental" thing!

Answer (score 2):

$V(x_2^2-x_1^3-x_1^2)$ is singular at $(0,0)$, while $V(x_1^2-x_2^2-1)$ has no singular points.